# Is there a way to find the bluetooth version without looking at a spec sheet?

Tags: bluetooth

What I was wondering is if there were any type of handshake process that happens when two Bluetooth devices connect that both tell each other what version of Bluetooth they support and just use the lowest available version that they both support. And if that negotiated version is stored anywhere for API use?

```
Android device: Bluetooth 4.2
IOT device: Bluetooth 4.0
Negotiated: Bluetooth 4.0
```

So from the example above the two devices have decided on using Bluetooth 4.0, now do system Bluetooth API's have access to viewing the negotiated version or does the Bluetooth chip just handle everything without offering that information?

Comment: In BLE there is a Link Layer control procedure (using LL_VERSION_IND Control PDU) that can be used for the controllers to exchange their Bluetooth version numbers after entering the Connection State.